# Simulate 360 degree object rotation using multiple images on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, animation

I would like to show a swipe-able 360 degree view of a product along a single axis by using multiple images stitched together to make it animated.

I'm new to iOS development, and am hoping to get pointed in the right direction to find libraries or built-in methods that could help me achieve this.  I'm guessing this is a fairly common task, but I'm not even sure of the correct terminology.  (I'm dabbling in RubyMotion as well, so that would be a bonus if it could work using that approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how i might do it:

1. get an image showing up in the ui, running on the phone, base case :)
2. make a 'ThreeSixtyImageView' (subclass of UIView) that contains a big UIImageView.
3. keep an NSArray of UIImages in your ThreeSixtyImageView class; load up all your UIImages into that array.
4. keep a number that's an index into that array.  when it changes, set the UIImageView image to the UIImage at that array index!  hook up a button that increments the index (and show that image) to make sure that works.
5. add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to track touch state
6. when the pan gesture begins, remember which image you're on, and where they tapped (as an anchor point)
7. when the pan gesture updates, subtract the anchor and divide by something that feels nice to get 'how much user wants images to rotate'.  this gives you a new image index value.
8. update your main UIImage with that new image index (into your array)

if there's a step here you don't understand, look in the examples included in the xcode/iOS documentation, and copy their code!  the sample code is pretty good, and helped me a lot with editing XIB documents, and learning about GestureRecognizers.

good luck!